# Optimal Cross-Device Unit for Column width

Tags: css, accessibility, typography

In typography, a column width of around 60-80 letters is considered optimal.

Is there some sort of unit which can be used to create some consistency within different devices, screens and pixel densities?

I've been absent in webdesign for some time, so please don't crucify me.
Is it rem em or whatever these days?

Or is there a reverse solution to resize the text to 60-80 letters per line?

Still wishful thinking?

Comment: I’m not clear whether you are wanting to find a font size on each device/viewport that would put 60-80 characters across the whole viewport, or whether you have a fixed font size, say something you have chosen which is likely to be readable,and you want to put the text into multi columns if there is room or… Could you elaborate?

Comment: The latter. A fixed font size whose lines will be broken down to 60-80 letters each @AHaworth

Comment: Ah, another relic from the print world. Welcome, brother/sister! Yours is a good question, but most good answers will be ambiguous. Typography on the Web is _always_ fluid typography; therefore, we can not set a column width based on a character width as you suggest. You can, however, mathematically create "ranges of readability" based on the viewport width and your base em size. For long texts I recommend using ```CSS``` viewport sensing and adding flex columns to accommodate. Short texts would not need anything so complicated and can set as one would set a poster face.